# Understanding Mongoose ObjectID and Validation Error when Saving a Scenario with User Reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a scenario object that I want to save using Mongoose. The scenario object has a "user" field, which should be an ObjectId referencing a "User" document. Here's the schema definition:

```
const Scenario = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    categories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }],
    questions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
    createdAt: { type: Number, default: Date.now, required: true },
    updatedAt: { type: Number, default: Date.now, required: true }
});
```

I'm passing the scenario data to Mongoose as follows:

```
const scenario = new Scenario({
    user: "user_id_here",
    name: "scenario1",
    categories: ["648da0a443d3568c50c873e7"]
});
await scenario.save();
```

However, when I check the saved scenario in the database, the `user` field is not set to the provided `user_id_here` value. Instead, it has a different value like `757365725f69645f68657265`. Why does this happen? (Noted that, neither `user_id_here` nor `757365725f69645f68657265` is an id in User table)

Also, if I change the `user` value to `user_id_here1`, I get a validation error: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value 'user_id_here1' (type string) at path 'user' because of 'BSONTypeError'.` What could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get an error by chance when the user value is `user_id_here` because it is 12 character length.

But when you use value `user_id_here1`, since it is 13 characters length you get validation error.

You can validate the user value using [isObjectIdOrHexString](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.isObjectIdOrHexString()) function before trying to save.

```
    const userId = "some value from request body or req params"

    if (!mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString(userId))
        return res.status(404).send('Invalid ID.');

    const scenario = new Scenario({
        user: userId,
        name: 'scenario1',
        ....
    });

    await scenario.save();
```

Comment: SuleymanSah, thanks but why it's "translated" the user_id_here to 757365725f69645f68657265 when storing?

Comment: @william007 it seems mongodb generates a valid object id itself when an invalid id passes.

Answer (score 0):

```
user:"user_id_here",
categories: ["648da0a443d3568c50c873e7"]
```

You are getting the error because you are passing the string.

Solution :
You have to parse the string into ObjectId using below code

```
user:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("user_id_here"),
categories: [new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("648da0a443d3568c50c873e7")]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to the way you're providing the user ID when creating a new scenario. Mongoose expects the user field to be assigned a valid ObjectId, but you're passing a string value instead. This is why Mongoose is not correctly mapping the provided value to the user field and generating a different value instead.

To resolve this, you need to ensure that you're passing a valid ObjectId for the user field. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ScenarioSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  categories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }],
  questions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
  createdAt: { type: Number, default: Date.now, required: true },
  updatedAt: { type: Number, default: Date.now, required: true }
});

const Scenario = mongoose.model('Scenario', ScenarioSchema);

// Assuming you have the user ID stored in a variable
const userId = "user_id_here"; // Replace with the actual user ID

const scenario = new Scenario({
  user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
  name: "scenario1",
  categories: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId("648da0a443d3568c50c873e7")]
});

await scenario.save();
```

By using mongoose.Types.ObjectId, you can create a valid ObjectId from the userId string. Make sure to replace "user_id_here" with the actual user ID you want to reference.

Regarding the validation error you mentioned when changing the user value to "user_id_here1," it occurs because the provided string doesn't represent a valid ObjectId format. Mongoose tries to cast the value to an ObjectId but fails due to the incorrect format. Make sure you provide a valid ObjectId value for the user field to avoid this validation error.